# How to use gtkmm without main arguments (argc/argv)?

Tags: gtkmm

I am trying to run an gtkmm3 application but it doesn't work !
My code :
    #include 
    #include

```
int main(void)
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);

  return (app->run(window));
}
```

And the error :

> gtkmm:ERROR:application.cc:157:int
>   Gtk::Application::run(Gtk::Window&): assertion failed: (m_argc) [1](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Application.html#a867c5d01ff51a30c53ba206da5f67217)
>   20729 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out

gdb told me the "app->run(window)" failed.

The [doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Application.html#a867c5d01ff51a30c53ba206da5f67217) says that there are two constructors, one with argc/argv and an other without.

If I use the first constructor, it works but i can't send an argument to my program because of gtk.

To compile, I use :

```
g++ test.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had that problem too. I ended up using the workaround shown in the sample below. Maybe someone else can shine in with a better solution to this problem.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  argc = 1;
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);

  return (app->run(window));
}
```

I 'lie' to Gtk::Application::create() by telling it that there were no argument in the command line. This way you can handle (or ignore) the command line arguments yourself. If you do not set argc to 1 and there are arguments, the app will abort with the message "This application can not open files". I hope this helps.